# Why doesn't the order of permutations matter when I build Riemann surfaces à la Hurwitz?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

I'm currently trying to construct simple Riemann Surfaces in the way of Hurwitz (see *e.g.* [here](https://publikationen.sulb.uni-saarland.de/bitstream/20.500.11880/26635/1/TropicalCover.pdf#page=16)):

> Given the complex plane $E$, which originates at $O$ and $w$ non-identical points $a_k$.
> Cut the plane from $O$ to each $a_k$, which shall be denoted as the cutted complex plane $E^*$. Cutlines are called $l_k$ and have a left and right side called $l^\pm_k$.
> Assume we have $n$ copies of $E^*$ and they are labelled, call'em $E^*_m$. At each $l_k$ there shall be a mapping $S_k$, i.e. a permutation, for which $$S_k: \{E^*_1,E^*_2,\dots,E^*_n\} \to \{E^*_{S_k(1)},E^*_{S_k(2)},\dots,E^*_{S_k(n)}\} $$
> holds.
> For my personal reason of interest, all my examples would further obey $w=n$.
> Hurwitz' construction of Riemann surfaces, asks for all permutations $S_k\in \mathbb S$ of the copies of the cutted complex planes $E^*$ at the branching points $a_k$, to fulfill:
> $$
> S_1S_2S_3\cdots S_w=1, \tag{1}
> $$
> which *ensures that there is no ramification at the origin.*

So I started to build some of these products of permutations based on ramification profile of length 3 (all permutations cycle 3 complex planes) and currently found some working examples for  $n=w=3$ and  $n=w=4$.

So I wonder why the order in $(1)$, the product of the elements of $\mathbb S$, seems to be of no interest. Why is that? What makes the difference from one ordering to the other, when I look at the resulting Riemann surface?

But after intense number crunching I also **found a counterexample** (based of [Heawood's graph](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=1154)) with $n=w=7$.

Remark: Due to my construction based on bipartite 3-regular graphs, I always assume $n=w$. I identify black vertices with the complex planes $E^*_m$ and white vertices with the (oriented) permutations $S_k$.

So obviously a subclass of sets $\mathbb S$, i.e. bicubic graphs, fulfills certain properties, to make $(1)$ to be true...

**UPDATE**: I found this reference
["The Riemann-Hurwitz formula for the centralizer of a pair of permutations"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01191186.pdf#page=8)
by Antonio Machi, making a somehow similarly unspecific statement about $(1)$ to be fulfilled *in some order*...